# setting timezone for timestamp in angular

Tags: angular, timestamp, timezone, unix-timestamp, gettime

Hello guys i looked the internet and here but i couldnt find the solutuon , anyway here is my problem.

I have a date and I need to convert this date to timestamp, but I need to do this according to canadian time. I am using the getTime() method, but this method converts to local time. As I change the clock of the pc, while my normal date remains constant, my timestamp date changes and this causes an error. Is there a method I can use instead of getTime() or how can I solve this problem? thanks for your solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to store time in utc+0 offset and when displaying you can use date pipe to format it according to the required time zone.

**Eg**

The user is prompted to enter a date. Users enter the date according to his/her current timezone. say the timezone is UTC+5 and the time entered is yyyy-mm-dd:18:00:00, then its UTC equivalent would be yyyy-mm-dd:13:00:00 (actualTime - 5 hours)

The date is converted to UTC+0 using JS date object, see [toUTCString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString)

And when that date is displayed back in app convert it back to current timezone using angular [datePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe). In this way time is synced is app is used in different timezones

Comment: okey i understood but the logic is like i send timestamp to backend and backend converts timestamp to canada date and backend returns startDay so if i send wrong timestamp , backend returns wrong day so this is not about datePipe :(

Comment: can you provide  a minimal reproduction?

Comment: here is my code  startDay.getTime() this makes local timestamp startDay is seems like Wed Oct 12 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00) and timestamp is 1665522000000 i want to set timestamp in canada timezone